# adding a newline to file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

Can any body help me with this simple thing in file handling?

The following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  ofstream savefile("anish.txt");
  savefile<<"hi this is first program i writer" <<"\n this is an experiment";
  savefile.close();
  return 0 ;
}
```

It is running successfully now, I want to format the output of the text file according to my way.

I have:

```
hi this is first program i writer this is an experiment
```

How can I make my output file look like the following:

```
hi this is first program 
I writer this is an experiment
```

What should I do to format the output in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to open the stream to write to a file:

```
ofstream file; // out file stream
file.open("anish.txt");
```

After that, you can write to the file using the `<<` operator:

```
file << "hi this is first program i writer";
```

Also, use `std::endl` instead of `\n`:

```
file << "hi this is first program i writer" << endl << "this is an experiment";
```

Comment: Use std::endl if you want the output flushed after printing a line. Otherwise '\n' is preferable. Flushing the buffer to often can lead to sub-optimal disk access.

Comment: Is this any different in Windows XP? endl and "\n" are both showing up as the small empty rectangles in my text file meaning unknown character?

Comment: "*First you need to open stream to write to a file*" - passing the filename to the `std::ofstream` constructor opens the file immediately, no need to call `open()` separately.

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 fstream file;
 file.open("source\\file.ext",ios::out|ios::binary);
 file << "Line 1 goes here \n\n line 2 goes here";

 // or

 file << "Line 1";
 file << endl << endl;
 file << "Line 2";
 file.close();
}
```

Again, hopefully this is what you want =)

Comment: I have similar code making a new ofstream file, opening it, then writing to it but both "\n" and << endl are not working for some reason. I just get the little rectangular box meaning it doesn't recognize the character, not sure if this is due to running Windows XP or what?

Comment: On Windows, the standard line break is `\r\n`, not `\n`. If the stream is opened in text mode (the default), `std::ofstream` *should* automatically convert `\n` to whatever the OS's standard line break is. If that is not happening for you, then either you opened the stream in binary mode, or you have a buggy STL implementation. As for `std::endl`, it simply writes a `\n` character to the stream and then flushes the stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Editor: MS visual studio 2019
// file name in the same directory where c++ project is created
// is polt ( a text file , .txt)
//polynomial1 and polynomial2 were already written
//I just wrote the result manually to show how to write data in file
// in new line after the old/already data
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("poly.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    if (!file) {
        cout << "File does not exist\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Writing\n";
            file << "\nResult: 4x4 + 6x3 + 56x2 + 33x1 + 3x0";  
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

**OUTPUT:** after running the data in the file would be
polynomial1: 2x3 + 56x2-1x1+3x0
polynomial2: 4x4+4x3+34x1+x0
Result: 4x4 + 6x3 + 56x2 + 33x1 + 3x0
The code is contributed by Zia Khan
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ios_base::app` instead (adding lines instead of overwriting):

```
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream savefile("anish.txt", ios_base::app);
    savefile<<"hi this is first program i writer" <<"\n this is an experiment";
    savefile.close();
    return 0 ;
}
```